# Как получить с каждого столбца таблицы QTableWidget отдельный массив?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qtablewidget

Пытался выводить массив данных с каждого столбца таблицы по этому вопросу:
[PyQt5. Считать значения столбца или строки таблицы без цикла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900232/)

Но безрезультатно. Если кто может напишите пример и объясните как он работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class TableExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QTableWidget(3, 3)
        self.fillButton = QPushButton(
            "Заполнить ячейки (выделенные ячейки)")
        self.fillButton.clicked.connect(self.onFill)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.fillButton)

    def onFill(self):
        for i, index in enumerate(self.table.selectedIndexes()):
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(str(i))
            self.table.setItem(index.row(), index.column(), item)

        self.get_column_data()               # +++

    def get_column_data(self):    
        rows = self.table.rowCount()         # Возвращает количество строк 
        columns = self.table.columnCount()   # Возвращает количество столбцов
         
        data = [ 
                   [self.table.item(row, column).text()
                       for row in range(rows)
                       if self.table.item(row, column) is not None
                   ] 
                   for column in range(columns)
               ]
               
        print(f"\ndata -> {data}\n")
        print(* data, sep='\n')
           

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TableExample()
    w.resize(400, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы немного не поняли вопрос. Мне необходимо что бы каждый столбец являлся массивом. Это нужно что бы работать с шаблонам таблицы как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280388/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-word-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-python/1280467#1280467

Comment: @Help_me что такое массив? Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: @Help_me мне не интересно, что вы будите делать дальше. Вы задали вопрос, я на него дал возможный вариант решения.

Comment: @Help_me то есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322595/1365), который я дал на аналогичный вопрос, заданный от другого вашего аккаунта, вам не помог?

Comment: Там все данные собирались в один массив. Мне необходимо что бы каждый столбец представлял собой отдельный массив. То есть для первого столбца массив data1 (к примеру) ко второму data2 и тд.

Comment: @Help_me я для вас так и сделал. Приведите что вы хотите получить, глядя на второе изображение в моем ответе.

Comment: Теперь эти данные должны загружаться в таблицу по шаблону в word. Как в этой статье: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280388/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-word-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-python/1280467#1280467

Comment: @Help_me это уже другой вопрос. Примите примите решение по данному вопросу.

Comment: Просто я не понимаю как этот код привязать к данной задаче. Ну ладно тогда создам отдельный вопрос для этого.

Comment: @Help_me, у меня такое ощущение, что вы с разных аккаунтов задаете один и тот же вопрос. Если это так, то это не правильно. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . В ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/ я вам показал альтернативный вариант и в методе `data_clipboar(self, d, model)` вы можете создать любую таблицу с подсчетом итогов или что там вам надо.

Comment: @Help_me "Там все данные собирались в один массив. Мне необходимо что бы каждый столбец представлял собой отдельный массив." как раз для вставки в шаблон ворд нужно все собирать в один массив, а не в десяток отдельных. Вы пробовали код из моего ответа?

Comment: @insolor, нет, не пробовал, но как я уже писал выше. в альтернативном варианте я могу создать любую таблицу.

Comment: @S.Nick, это не вам ответ был, а Help_me )

Comment: @insolor, sorry :)